# How do I update a postgres boolean field using Active Record in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I created a join table like so:

```
class CreateJoinTablePurchaseUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :purchases, :users, table_name: :participation_requests do |t|
    # t.index [:purchase_id, :user_id]
    # t.index [:user_id, :purchase_id]
    t.boolean :approved, default: false
  end
end
```

And here is my model:

```
class ParticipationRequest < ApplicationRecord
end
```

I created a row in the table successfully. However, when I try to update the boolean value like so:

```
pr = ParticipationRequest.find_by(user_id: 1, purchase_id: 1)
pr.update_attributes(approved: true)
```

pr returns the row and I get a ROLLBACK on the update with this message:

```
TypeError: nil is not a symbol nor a string
```

I recognized that the join table is different from my other tables in that it is not indexed like my regular tables. The primary key seems to be a combination of the user_id and purchase_id. I have no problem using update_attributes on any of my other tables. Is there something different about this join table that will not allow me to update an attribute this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create_join_table` creates table without primary key. And `ActiveRecord` can't update record without primary key. So you can't change any field in record, neither `approved` neither `user_id` or `purchase_id`. (Rails believes you should not manually update records of "join tables")

If you need to change records of models like this you may use gem [Composite Primary Keys](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys).

Add gem to `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'composite_primary_keys'
```

Add unique index to the table (this is optional but better to do):

```
class AddUniqueIdnexToParticipationRequests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change    
    add_index :participation_requests, [:purchase_id, :user_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

And set `primary_keys` to your model:

```
class ParticipationRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_keys = :purchase_id, :user_id

  belongs_to :purchase
  belongs_to :user
end
```

That's all, now your "join table" records should be able to update.